# Django Distance Search by Zipcode

Tags: django, search, distance

I want to search based on distance from inputted US zipcode.

First, I know I need a search form:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    zipcode = forms.CharField(max_length=5)
```

Then I pass those options to next view where I filter based on inputted parameters. This is where it gets tricky for me.. I have searched around a lot and it seems there are many solutions to this. I have used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229827/django-is-geodjango-a-good-fit-for-my-website) as a reference would give me something like this:

```
def display_map(request, zipcode):
    objects_near_zip = Thing.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=(Point([zipcode]), D(mi=5)))
```

But I need to turn the zipcode into a point. How would I do this? Is there a better solution that you have used? Thanks for your ideas!

---

EDIT:

I found [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/geodjango/butW7zJQhSw/FuRQ09VbI3cJ), but the implementation is a little hard for me to understand. I create a `Zipcode` model, that makes sense.

But Im not sure how or where to load the zipcodes like he says in the post:

```
lm = LayerMapping(Zipcode, 'tl_2008_us_zcta5.shp',
                   { 'code' : 'ZCTA5CE',
                     'mpoly' : 'MULTIPOLYGON',
                   })
lm.save()
```

Where do I place this code? The shp file is quite large and took a long time even on my desktop, so Im not sure this is the best solution.

Comment: The post that you linked to pretty much covers this completely. You create the point in your model. There is also a link in the answer of that post that directs you to a list of all zip codes and their "points". What exactly is your question?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sorry, but it is not as clear to me as to you: see my edit above. Where does one 'load' the zipcodes from the shp file? In the view? It seems like this information is better in the database, correct? Thanks for your input.